# How to detect collision between three objects simultaneously in Box2D?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, box2d

I am new to Objective-C. I am currently working on a game using Cocos2D and Box2D. My problem is that when 3 objects collide together, the game crashes. Now let me describe my game in details:

In my game I have a main character standing on top of a building. Below the building there's this the road. Enemies pass by the road at various random speeds entering the screen from right and exiting from the left. I have created the enemies as `b2_kinematicBodies` and set a random velocity for each of them using `SetLinearVelocity()`. The main character shoots the enemies. The projectile (the object being shot) is a `b2_dynamicBody`. When the projectile hits the enemies, both the projectile and the enemy are destroyed. During gameplay sometimes an enemy moving at a slow speed is crossed by one which is moving at a higher speed. If a projectile hits the two enemies just at the point when they are overlapping and one is about to pass the other one, the game crashes! Please help me with this.

I have detected collision using `b2contactListener` class.

One thing I didn't mention before is that I am not creating the enemies as individual distinct bodies. Instead, I am creating it once and making it move and I am calling this method (which creates the enemies and makes them move) inside init as below:

```
[self schedule:@selector(addRightTarget) interval:2.0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the collisions are calculated before your handler gets any calls.  Meaning that when your handler gets called, the bullet has hit 2 objects.  So you get 2 call-backs as shown below.

Collision Detected: Bullet + Enemy1

- Destroy Enemy1
- Destroy Bullet

Collision Detected: Bullet + Enemy2

- Destroy Enemy2
- Destroy Bullet  [CRAAAASH!!! You just tried to delete a non-existent object]

1st: You should not be removing anything except in your step function (as someone mentioned in another answer)

2nd: Pick one of these:

- Make your list/array of objects-to-delete be a 'set' or implemented in such a way that duplicates are avoided.
- Check for existence of your object in the world

Answer (score 1):

The collision only happens between 2 objects in Box2D. So in your mentioned scenario your will get multiple collision events which could be,

Enemy-1 and Enemy-2
Enemy-1 and Bullet
Enemy-2 and Bullet

So one possible reason of crash could be that you are not expecting (Enemy-1 and Enemy-2) collision and you are handling it like you have collision between (Enemy-1 and Bullet) so you might be casting it into wrong class. Make sure you are checking the kind of class "isKindOf" before casting it.
Also you may want to use Contact Filtering and or assign category masks to your enemies so that they don't collide with each other and only collide with bullet.

But it will be more help full if you tell something about how and where you destroy your bodies (I hope its not inside your Collision Detection Functions) and also if you can share the exception text when your application crash, that will be helpful.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "casting into wrong class". Pardon me since I am new to objective-c and in fact programming itself. I have destroyed the bodies inside my collision detection function. Unfortunately I dont get an exception text when the app crashes.

Comment: Normally my enemies dont collide with each other(bounce off). I think this is because I have created them as kinematic bodies. Instead the one with higher speed passes through the other(one with slower speed) as if the other one didnt exist!
Btw, I really appreciate your attempt to help me! Thanks!

Comment: Yes as far as kinematic bodies are concerned, they don't collide with each other.

Comment: And if you try to destroy bodies from within your collision detection function (e.g: PreSolve, BeginContact etc...). Because at the same time when you are deleting that body, your physics world's "step()" function maybe performing calculations on it in other thread. So solution is that you just add that body in an array and then delete that body in the same function where your "step()" function is called. you can delete the bodies that you have added in array just before you called the step() function. I hope you understand.

Comment: Thanx. I understood what you said and I did that but that didnt help. Instead, I alternately created enemy fixtures of different sizes(differing by few pixels). So now if i shoot them even when they overlap, the app doesn't crash(because only the bigger object collides and gets destroyed). This serves my purpose. Than a llot for your help. I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I used a rather cheap workaround.  I alternately created enemy fixtures of different sizes(differing by few pixels). So now if i shoot them even when they overlap, the app doesn't crash(because only the bigger object collides and gets destroyed). This serves my purpose. Thanx a llot for your help. I really appreciate it! :)